# Mapbox,leaflet: Increase marker size on Zoom

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

How can I increase the size of all  markers when we zoom in the map?
I know we can use `map.on('zoomend', function() {});` and change the icon size inside the function.But I have a lot of markers and looping through all of them and changing them individually doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: LOL @IvanSanchez. Deepak, this is not the kind of question Stackoverflow wants to see. Some more effort is required like, how did you try to solve it yourself? What did your research turn up? What solutions did you try? Why didn't it work? What errors did you get? Etc. Take a few minutes and read this please: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask then come back and edit your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with looping through a set of markers on every `zoomend` event. Why doesn't it sound like a good idea?

An alternative to looping through markers is to extend the `L.Marker` class to do the work for you, something like:

```
L.Marker.Autoresizable = L.Marker.extend({

    onAdd: {
        map.on('zoomend', this._changeIcon, this);
    },

    onRemove: function(map) {
        map.off('zoomend', this._changeIcon, this);
    },

    _changeIcon: function(ev) {
        var zoom = this._map.getZoom();

        if (zoom <= 10) {
            this.setIcon(...);
        } elseif (zoom > 10 && zoom <= 15) {
            this.setIcon(...);
        } else {
            this.setIcon(...);
        }

    }

});

L.marker.autoresizable = function(latlng, options) {
    return new L.Marker.Autoresizable(latlng, options);
}
```

In this case, the Leaflet code will implicitly loop through all the event listeners for the `zoomend` event, which is pretty much the same (performance-wise) as looping through the markers yourself.