# Best way to make marker resizable in leaflet

Tags: javascript, google-maps, leaflet, ui-leaflet

I am trying to resize my markers every time the map is zoomed in or out. 
Currently I am using this approach:

- Iterate all markers in zoomend method.
- get current icon size
- Perform some calculation to get the new marker size according the zoom size.
- set the new dimension to the icon object.

  ```
  map.on('zoomend', function() {
  zoomEndLevel = map.getZoom();
  var difference = zoomEndLevel - zoomStartLevel;
  console.log("difference in zoom " + difference);
  markerArray.forEach(function(marker) {
      var icon = marker.options.icon;
      var oldX = icon.options.iconSize[0];
      var oldY = icon.options.iconSize[1];
      var newX = getNewIconAxis(oldX, difference);
      var newY = getNewIconAxis(oldY, difference);
      console.log(newX + " " + newY);
      icon.options.iconSize = [ newX, newY ];
      marker.setIcon(icon);
  });
  ```

  });

  ```
  map.on('zoomstart', function() {
  zoomStartLevel = map.getZoom();
  ```

  });

  ```
  function getNewIconAxis(value, zoomChange) {
  if (zoomChange > 0) {
      for (var i = zoomChange; i > 0; i--) {
          value = value * 2;
      }
  } else {
      for (var i = zoomChange; i < 0; i++) {
          value = value / 2;
      }
  }
  return value;
  ```

  }

Problem : 
This code works fine if I zoom in and out 1 level at once. If I scroll in and out my mouse too frequently then this code given strange outputs. Sometimes the marker size becomes too large or too small.

Question :
1) Is this the only way to make the markers resizable on different zoom levels?
2) If yes then what am I missing here or what changes should be made to make it work perfectly.?

Note : Tagging google maps also because it's more of a logical  issue with map (either google or leaflet or mapbox) rather than api specific issue.

Comment: Why have you tagged Google-maps as well as leaflet? Please format your code & question in a readable format!!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are several previous posts that you guide you:

- [Mapbox,leaflet: Increase marker size on Zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35452705/mapbox-leaflet-increase-marker-size-on-zoom)
- [is there a way to resize marker icons depending on zoom level in leaflet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382012/is-there-a-way-to-resize-marker-icons-depending-on-zoom-level-in-leaflet)
- https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171609/resize-divicons-svgs-at-zoom-levels-leaflet

As for your bug, instead of reading the current icon size `value` at `"zoomstart"` event, you might better remember the previous zoom value and read it only at `"zoomend"` event. I am not sure the `"zoomstart"` event is fired only once when you scroll (to zoom in/out) successively, while the `"zoomend"` event may be fired only at the very end.