# leaflet icon size based on meters

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geo

I want to display objects on a map in their exact dimensions.

I have reference data about these objects, containing the length and width of the object in meters, now I need to convert the meters into pixels for the leaflet icon size based on the zoom level.

```
var meterlength = 50;
var meterwidth = 40;

//convert meters to pixels

var icon = L.divIcon({html:"<svg>..</svg>",iconSize:[xx,yy]});
```

I found this https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.GeometryUtil/

GeometryUtils with the length and distance function, but could not get it working.

Any ideas ? Thank you very much !

EDIT:

This answer solved my original problem:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/198444

But I'm sacling the icons on map zoom using the "zoomanim" event - unfortunately the *map.containerPointToLatLng()* Methode applies to the old zoom level not to the new one. 
Is there a Workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your image to represent the object real size, then you should probably better use an `L.imageOverlay` instead of a marker and trying to adjust its size based on zoom level.

See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171609/resize-divicons-svgs-at-zoom-levels-leaflet

Then you would need to find the appropriate *coordinates* for your Image Overlay *bounds*, not pixels.

Now if you *really* want to change your marker icon size depending on the zoom level, you have several posts on SO and GIS SE that cover this topic.

E.g. [Best way to make marker resizable in leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35984623/best-way-to-make-marker-resizable-in-leaflet/36003439#36003439)

Comment: I updated my question .. imageoverlay is a nice idea, but im using divIcons and svg, I thought it would make no difference, sorry!

Comment: For Image Overlay with SVG, see the JSFiddle examples in the comments of the 1st link in the above answer.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/58/ I think you mean this, in my opinion they load png's there :o

Comment: try next comments

Comment: ahh good idea, I will check if this could solve my problem, thanks